# Limit results from Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

So my Reducer is:

```
const initialState = {
  1: {
     id: '1',
     user: 'User1',
     text: 'Dummy Text id1',
     SomeFiled: 'SomeValue',
    },
  2: {
     id: '2',
     user: 'User1',
     text: 'Dummy Text id2',
     SomeFiled: 'SomeValue',
    },
  3: {
     id: '3',
     user: 'User1',
     text: 'Dummy Text id3',
     SomeFiled: 'SomeValue',
    },
  4: {
     id: '4',
     user: 'User1',
     text: 'Dummy Text id4',
     SomeFiled: 'SomeValue',
    },
  5: {
     id: '5',
     user: 'User1',
     text: 'Dummy Text id5',
     SomeFiled: 'SomeValue',
    }
}
```

I've `mapStateToProps` with prop `users` and able to show the data:

```
const renData = Object.keys(this.props.users).map((key, idx) => {
let user = this.props.users[key]
 return(
     <View key={idx} style={styles.myStyle}>
         <Text style={styles.myStyleText}>
             { user.id } - { user.user } - { user.Text }
         </Text>
     </View>
     )
});
```

I want to show only 2 objects from the Reducer. So the first `(id: '1')` and second `(id: '2')` but not based on `id`, only the first 2. And then have a `Button` which `onPress` will load more 2 values. And If there are any more values, the button will show, else not show. Not worried about the display of the Button for now. I want to know how to apply limit in rendering values from a reducer.

Many thanks.

Comment: have a variable that will hold the items count that you want to render, and write it like this `Object.keys(this.props.users).slice(0,2).map(......`, in place of 2 use that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `slice` method.

The `slice()` method returns a `shallow` copy of a **portion** of an array into a `new` array object selected from **begin** to **end** (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```
let size=2;
const renData = Object.keys(this.props.users).slice(0,size).map((key, idx) => {
let user = this.props.users[key]
 return(
     <View key={idx} style={styles.myStyle}>
         <Text style={styles.myStyleText}>
             { user.id } - { user.user } - { user.Text }
         </Text>
     </View>
     )
});
```

You can declare an `object` in the `state` of the `component`:

```
this.state={
    data:{
       count:count,
       dataArray:array
    }
}
```

and use `setState` method in order to `bind` values.

```
this.setState({
  data: {
        count:newCount
        dataArray: newArray
       }
});
```

Comment: Can I use `React State` with Reducers? Reducer is from `Redux` reducer. Testing the code.

Answer (score 1):

The same scenario what are you are expecting with pure JS. Using same [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) logic as @MayankShukla said.

```js
var count = 0;
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
function renderMore(){
  count+= 2;
  if(count > data.length) {
    count = data.length;
    document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  }
  let renData = data.slice(0,count);
  console.log(renData)
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="renderMore()">Show more</button>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a state variable inside component, that will hold the count of items that you want to render, initial value of that variable will be 2.

Then use [#array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the part of data, and run [#array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on it, To load more items, update the count of that variable.

Write it like this:

```
const renData = Object.keys(this.props.users).slice(0, 2).map((key, idx) => {
     ......
}
```

**Note:** In place of two use that variable.

Comment: Say `var toShow = 2`, so on button `onPress`  update `toShow` to 4 and render `renData` again?

Comment: nope, you need to make it a state variable, so that any change in that variable will re-render the component.

Comment: @Somename, have a look to my answer.

Comment: @MayankShukla, yes, he should use `state` in order to update and bind `new` values.